# Why is jasmine unable to find my unit tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

my folder structure looks like this
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y70vy.png)

my jasmine.json file

```
{
    "spec_dir": "dist/tests",
    "spec_files": ["**/*[sS]pec.js"],
    "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.js"],
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": false
}
```

if i make a simple unit test
on index.ts

```
const myFunc = (num: number): number => {
  return num * num;
};

export default myFunc;
```

and on indexSpec.ts

```
import myFunc from '../index';

it('expect myFunc(5) to equal 25', () => {
  expect(myFunc(5)).toEqual(25);
});
```

i get this output

> No specs found
> Finished in 0.007 seconds
> Incomplete: No specs found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you specify that you want to test files with the .js extension but you are coding in a .ts

Comment: i've tried changing it to .ts and change the "spec_dir" in the json file to be "src/tests" but i get another error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: I guess the new error is from your package.json or tsconfig, with the modification does your package .json have this field:     type: “module“, ? Elle see on stack overflow this error (import outside of module) is an Roger topic with a lot of solutions

Comment: thank you it was as you said type : module in my package.json i changed this and modified the spec_dir so it points to the right directory (the build directory where files compile to js files instead of typescript) and it worked